# Was anything actually accomplished?

Tags: realm-of-the-elderlings

Throughout the Tawny Man trilogy ...

> the Fool is focused on saving the dragons and bringing them back into the world. To that end they eventually rescue Icefyre, who mates with Tintaglia and they go on to produce new eggs (eventually), thus saving the dragon race and ensuring their survival at least until the next generation.

However, in the Rain Wilds Chronicles ...

> The baby dragons do eventually become full dragons which are capable of mating and reproducing.  Moreover, Icefyre doesn't seem to have any important role in any of this, and doesn't interact with them in any way until they're already fully grown.  Wouldn't the dragons have reproduced perfectly well even if the Pale Woman had killed Icefyre? And if so, wouldn't the Fool be able to see that?

Comment: Is anything ever?

Answer (score 1):

It could be argued without Titaglia saving Bingtown, and getting that agreement to protect and care for the next generation of dragons, they would not have survived. Perhaps harvested by Chalced as dragons or Bingtown as wizardwood.

Edit: In terms of IceFyre my memory is foggy with the reading of the rain wild chronicles as I didn't enjoy that much. But a closer examination to what he did in both series may determine the answer to your question. (Direct interactions in Rain Wild, and perhaps the rippling effect of his presence and plot importance in the Tawny Man) Currently I can't recall IceFyre doing anything particularly altruistic for the 2nd generation of dragons (or Tintaglia).

I will update this with any new thoughts that come to me.

Comment: That I'd agree with, but I was more thinking about whether the events in the Tawny Man mattered (at least in the sense of protecting the dragons), since there ended up being a new generation of dragons without Icefyre

Answer (score 1):

### Yes it was

For starters, please note that the first generation of dragons that we can see (that are not offspring of Titaglia) is weak and deformed, it took them long, long time to reach something approaching the full dragon strength. For a long time they had to rely on hunters to feed themselves, they were unable to fly and have lost access to most of their "genetic memories". Few of them are even mentally retarded - we do not know how good their offspring will be, even assuming that they can bear one. On the contrast offspring of Tingtalia and Icefyre will again be born without any defects.

Secondary you forget about another problem: Duke of Chalced was looking for dragon components to cure his illness and extend his lifespan. He had strong, fanatical army so if he wished to, he could easily wreck havoc on weakened Six Duchess, thus - as the Pale Lady wanted - starting the end of current civilisation. Also, arguably without Icefyre's help Tingtalia could be killed by Chalcedian forces, which would make the Bingtown vulnerable.

Comment: Those are good points! Thanks! I think this answer is right, however I think you're confusing Jamaillia with Chalced; the Duke of Chalced was the one hunting desperately for dragon parts, and whose troops wounded Tintaglia.

Comment: I stand correncted, indeed it was Chalced - its been a while since I've read it.